# PHP Arrays: loop keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check the longest side of an triangle:

The lenghts and the sides are saved in an array ($allSides)

Now I want to display the lagest side of all! I Want to check
the longest with an "foreach-action":

```
<?php

  triangle(1, 5, 5);


  function triangle($a, $b, $c) {

    $allSides = array(
      'a' => $a,
      'b' => $b,
      'c' => $c
    );

    if($a < $b + $c || $b < $a + $c || $c < $a + $b) {

      echo " | Das Dreieck ist konstruierbar! <br>";

      $U = $a + $b + $c;

      echo " | Umfang: ".$U."<br>";


      $longestSide = max($allSides);

      $allSidesKeys = getSideKey($longestSide, $allSides);

      $keys = implode(", ", $allSidesKeys);


      echo "| Längste Seite(".$keys."): ".$longestSide."<br>";

    } else {}

  }

  function getSideKey($longestSide, $allSides) {

    $allSidesKeys = array();

    foreach($allSides as $key => $value) {

      echo $key.$value;

      if($value == $longestSide) {

        array_push($allSidesKeys, $key);

        print_r($allSidesKeys);

        return $allSidesKeys;

      }

    }

  }

?>
```

But when I check, if the $value of the side (lenght) == to the longest side, the if
stops. And if there are 2 sides with the same lenght I want to display them TWO.

I want to save both of the sides with the same lenght in an array too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `return $allSidesKeys;` outside of the `if` and `for` blocks. Otherwise it returns on the first match.

This is how your function will look like:
function getSideKey($longestSide, $allSides) {

```
$allSidesKeys = array();

foreach($allSides as $key => $value) {

  echo $key.$value;

  if($value == $longestSide) {

    array_push($allSidesKeys, $key);

    print_r($allSidesKeys);

    }

  }   
  return $allSidesKeys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier.  Just get the `max` as you have and then us `array_keys` to get the keys that have that value:

```
function triangle($a, $b, $c) {

    $allSides = get_defined_vars();
    
    $longestSide  = max($allSides);
    echo $longestSide . PHP_EOL;
    
    $allSidesKeys = array_keys($allSides, $longestSide);
    echo implode(',', $allSidesKeys) . PHP_EOL;
    
    return $allSidesKeys;
}

$result = triangle(1, 5, 5);
```